# Cannot apply operator '&&' to operands of type 'bool' and 'Fuel.LoanPayments.LoanPayment'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I try to write mapper with pre condition

Here is Code

```
configuration.CreateMap<Loan, LoanDto>()
    .ForMember(x=> x.NextPaymentAmount, opt =>
    {
        opt.PreCondition(
            src => (src.DirectDebitCollection.Count > 0) &&
                   (src.LoanPayments
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                           x.LoanPaymentStatusId == (int)LoanPaymentStatusEnum.Due)));
                
                opt.MapFrom(src=> src.DirectDebitCollection);
    });
```

But at this row   `opt.PreCondition(src => (src.DirectDebitCollection.Count > 0) && (src.LoanPayments.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.LoanPaymentStatusId == (int)LoanPaymentStatusEnum.Due)));`

I got this error

> Cannot apply operator '&&' to operands of type 'bool' and 'Fuel.LoanPayments.LoanPayment'

How I need to rewrite it?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns an object and not a boolean value, so of course you cannot AND its result with a boolean value. What is the condition you are trying to check for?

Comment: This sub-expression: `(src.LoanPayments.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.LoanPaymentStatusId == (int)LoanPaymentStatusEnum.Due))` should also return a true/false value, so you need to figure out what kind of question you're answering here.

Comment: Did you mean to use `.Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because

```
(src.LoanPayments
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoanPaymentStatusId == (int)LoanPaymentStatusEnum.Due))
```

returns an item from the list

If you use

```
(src.LoanPayments
    .Any(x => x.LoanPaymentStatusId == (int)LoanPaymentStatusEnum.Due)))
```

it will return true if an item exist and false if non exist in the list